# Is there a way to switch from android studio snap to android studio deb?

Tags: android, snap, android-studio

I've installed Android Studio from the snap, but I want to upgrade my Android Studio beta version. But the snap package doesn't provide a beta package of android studio. Therefore I want to switch from snap to official method of installing android studio without losing my settings, projects and SDKs. If there is any way, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back up your projects and SDKs, you may have to reconfigure your settings but it's a small price to pay, uninstall the snap package and install the package from the [Official Android Studio Website](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) and then reload your projects and SDKs from the backup you made. You could also do the nuclear option of just not backing anything up but that's not recommended. You should find your projects `/home/USER/AndroidStudio/` unless you saved them to a different directory.